# load and execute external program (many times)

Tags: c#

I need to execute external program with arguments and get result from it (~1000 times with different arguments).
I found solution like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "qwe 123";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
// And check exit code for result
```

I need many repetitions with different arguments, but this code every time initiate new process. It is very expensive operation. I think, i can "load" ("save") process and repeat it without everytime initiating.
Or maybe exist other way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is almost completely dependant on the process you are starting. Your solution begins there. If that process does not provide you with means to change those arguments at run-time, you probably have no other choice than restart the whole process each time.

Comment: @pyrocumulus you mean that i can make my process program so that it can take and return some values without its ending?

Comment: @pyrocumulus if it's possible, i can change my process programm as i wish

Comment: Even if you couldn't change the program, you'd be better off by calling it from a PowerShell script, that would loop through all the argument combinations and call the program once per set of arguments.

Comment: Basically: no. If `process.exe` does not provide a way to run `batch-like` arguments you don't have a lot of options. Try to get some documentation. Maybe there are some DLL's you can hook in to.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Why do you find it better to execute a program 1000 times than to let it read 1000 words from stdin?

Comment: I was also not sure whether it would be possible to re-use a process control after the program that was started through it had exited (and call Start() on it again). I read the relevant documentation and googled some but had a hard time finding authoritative information. That `Process` must potentially be disposed does not per se preclude re-use.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I don't. I said "if you couldn't change the program".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Oh. I see. Now. There was a negation...

Answer (score 0):

If the started process is under your control it will be much more efficient to pass the input not via command line parameter for a new process instance every time, but re-program it so that the process reads its standard input line-wise in a loop, processes each line, and writes the result to its standard output. It's easy to hook up the calling program to the process' input and output:

```
// ...
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
// ...
process.Start();

StreamReader results = process.StandardOutput;
StreamWriter processInput = process.StandardInput;

foreach( var arg in args )
{
    processInput.WriteLine(arg);
    var oneResult = results.ReadLine();
    // do something with this oneResult
}
```

This example assumes that each argument fits in one line (and each result fits in a line, too). Writing and reading a single line each time  is our simple "protocol" for knowing when to start processing (on the process side) and when the result is complete (on the C# side).

I should perhaps add that a real program should add error handling and e.g. evaluate `Process.Start()`'s return value.